# How can you apply ranks to subgroups in SAS?

Tags: loops, sas, rank

Disclaimer: this is homework.

I have a SAS dataset of:

```
ID    VAL   YEAR
```

I need to group them into 10 groups by `YEAR`

So, in my case the years go from 1980 to 2000, and each year has many rows.

If I wanted to rank the entire set I would do this:

```
proc rank groups=10 data=foo out=bar;
var val; ranks s1; run;
```

But that doesn't separate them by year. So I tried to put it into a `DO` loop and `APPEND` each year's ranked data like this:

```
do i=0 to 20;
data z; set l;
if year = 1980 + i;
keep id year val;
run;

proc append  base=l data=z;
run;
end;
run;
```

But it doesn't recognize `i` as a variable, and it doesn't append any data.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Since you stated that this was for homework, you might want to learn why your DO loop code did not work.  DO/TO - END is code that is specific to a DATA STEP.  For your example you will instead need to use MACRO logic, such as %DO/%TO - %END.  Also the "1980 + i" would need to be changed to "1980 + &i".  Finally, all of this needs to be written within a macro definition. The answer that Robbie provided is much more efficient, but it's good to see that you were thinking of other options too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this is just what you want. if you would like to do `rank` by a variable, just state `by` statement of `proc rank`. Also ensure the data set has been sorted by year before executing this.

```
proc rank groups=10 data=foo out=bar;
var val; 
ranks s1; 
by year;
run;
```

Comment: I think this just ranks regardless of year. If I rank just one year, its result is different

Comment: I just verified, your method does not work. It ranks by  val regardless of the year.

Comment: please provide a data example describing the original and what it would be after transforming. `by` statement will make ranks in every subgroup of year. So I don't really understand you say it ignores "year".

Comment: You are correct if you append `by year;` after `ranks s1;`  Update your answer and I'll mark it! Thanks.

Comment: Without the `by year;` the ranking doesn't consider the `year` column at all and just ranks them regardless of year.